# building a dockerfiile works, but referencing it from a compose and running it fails. Not sure if it is dockerfile file path err?

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

File Hierarch:

```
|- docker-compose.yml
|- database/
|  |- Dockerfile
|  |- db_schema.sql
```

I have a simple Dockerfile which will build and run.

```
FROM postgres:10

ENV POSTGRES_USER=foo
ENV POSTGRES_PASSWORD=password
ENV POSTGRES_DB=foo

COPY ./db_schema.sql /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/

EXPOSE 5432
```

There is a db_schema.sql file in the same directory which get copied.
This works as expected.

Now I wanted to expand upon this with a docker-compose file

```
version: '2.0'
services:
    database:
        build: ./database/.
        ports: 
            - "5432:5432"
```

It seemed simple enough.
The issue now is that when i say `docker-compose up` it will return:

```
database_1  | Error: Database is uninitialized and superuser password is not specified.
database_1  |        You must specify POSTGRES_PASSWORD to a non-empty value for the
database_1  |        superuser. For example, "-e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=password" on "docker run".
database_1  | 
database_1  |        You may also use "POSTGRES_HOST_AUTH_METHOD=trust" to allow all
database_1  |        connections without a password. This is *not* recommended.
database_1  | 
database_1  |        See PostgreSQL documentation about "trust":
database_1  |        https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/auth-trust.html
backend_database_1 exited with code 1
```

But they were initialized in the dockerfile.  Do ENV variables need to be set in the docker compose and not set in the dockerfile itself?

When looking at: https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/
it was saying that docker-compose takes presidence over dockerfile, but if they arent defined, that they just use the dockerfile env variables.  Yet this error comes still, which seems to be throwing me off.

Comment: I'm trying to reproduce and see what's wrong. Can you please provide a sample of the db_schema.sql you are using? It worked on my side without changing anything in the files that you provided

Comment: I commented out the db_schema.sql file so it wasnt a part of builds to see if I could still get this issue and it seems to also not work.  i am trying to narrow it for you.

Comment: Are you running docker on Linux or Windows. I added the results from my machine. Everything goes fine, and also went fine at the first attempt when the DB was not initialized. Try to delete the image, to force it to be rebuilt

Comment: @NeoAnderson is there a way to do a docker-compose purge or something similar as maybe there is an issue with my Mac?

Comment: `docker image ls | grep postgres`, look for the postgres image that is being built by the compose file, then `docker image rm <imageID>`

Comment: "unable to delete.  Image has dependant child images" 0_0  I have a bunch of images I need to remove that are unnamed, untagged, etc.

Comment: Remove all stopped containers: `docker container prune`. Remove dangling images: `docker image prune`. If you are not on prod server and don't risk add `-a` to delete all unused images

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I tried to reproduce, the error didn't occur, with the exact files provided in the question. The real cause was an old image being built incorrectly.

Edit after the problem was reproduced, with a faulty image:

To force the rebuild of the image, the following command can be used:

```
docker-compose up --build
```

The environment variables can also be provided thought the compose file:

```
 environment:
   - POSTGRES_USER=foo
   - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=password
   - POSTGRES_DB=foo
```

Deleting the image can also solve the problem.

Comment: When attempting with the environment in the compose, it wrorks.  When doing it from within the Dockerfile it doesnt.  Interesting.

Comment: The image must have been build differently at some point in time, perhaps without the vars. Try `docker-compose up --build`. This will force the image to be rebuilt

Comment: The `--build` worked!  I guess it was retaining and reusing a built image previously.  That was lame, but it has since started working. Thanks Neo.  If you can add the build to your answer, ill make give you all the credit

Comment: Glad we found the problem. You can also force the image to be built under a different name, if you set a different project name: `docker-compose -p new-name up`. I will clean-up the mess in the answer